# Python: Provide All Possible Sums Between Different Values of Variables

Tags: python

Maybe you will be able to help me to solve somewhat simple issue - I am trying to figure out how domain of possible outcomes look.

1. Imagine I have multiple variables with different set of potential values:

```
A = [0.9, 0.7, 1, 0.5]
B = [0, 1]
C = [0.3, 0.6, 0.9]
D = [-1.8, 0]
```

I need a list of all possible sums of different values between these variables, for example:

```
- sum1: 0.9 + 0 + 0.3 + (-1.8) = -0.6
- sum2: 0.9 + 1 + 0.3 + (-1.8) =  0.4
- sum3: 0.9 + 0 + 0.6 + (-1.8) = -0.3
```

Best case scenario data should be in dataframe and if there are some true magicians scenario could be identified next to each output, for example

| Scenario | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| A0.9_B0_C0.3_D-1.8 | -0.6 |
| A0.9_B1_C0.3_D-1.8 | 0.4 |

Hope you can help me to crack this! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this quite simply with the help of Numpy!

**1)  Initialise your lists as np.array**:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0.9, 0.7, 1, 0.5])
B = np.array([0, 1])
C = np.array([0.3, 0.6, 0.9])
D = np.array([-1.8, 0])
```

**2) Create all possible combinations with np.meshgrid()**:

```py
combinations = np.array(
  np.meshgrid(A,B,C,D)).T.reshape(-1,4)
)
```

**3) Calculate sums across all combinations (rows):**

```py
sums = combinations.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
```

**4) Build Pandas dataframe:**

```py
import pandas as pd

arrays = ['A','B','C','D']
combinations_df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([combinations,sums]), columns=arrays+['sum'])
combinations_df.head()
```

**Output:**

[image]

By using numpy arrays instead of lists you'll be able to make the code more readable and robust since all operations will be vectorised.

**Now to get a "scenario" column `scenario` we can use two simple apply's:**

```py
combinations_df['scenario'] = combinations_df[arrays].apply(
  lambda row: [f'{c[1]}{c[0]}' for c in list(zip(row,combinations_df.columns[:-1]))],
  axis=1
).apply(lambda row: '_'.join(row))
combinations_df.head()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
Note that you can re-arrange the order of the for-loops, if you want the output in a specific order.

```
import pandas as pd

A = [0.9, 0.7, 1, 0.5]
B = [0, 1]
C = [0.3, 0.6, 0.9]
D = [-1.8, 0]

scenario, my_sum = [], []
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        for c in C:
            for d in D:
                scenario.append(f"A{a}_B{b}_C{c}_D{d}")
                my_sum.append(round(a+b+c+d, 2))
                
result = {"Scenario":scenario, "SUM":my_sum}                
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result)
print(df.head(5))
```

#### Output:

Showing only the first 5 results:

[image: df]

**By re-arranging the for-loops:**

```
for d in D:
    for c in C:
        for b in B:
            for a in A:
                scenario.append(f"A{a}_B{b}_C{c}_D{d}")
                my_sum.append(round(a+b+c+d, 2))
```

You get the following result for the first 5 rows:

[image: df2]